# Is code stored in private repositories on github encrypted?

Tags: github, encryption

Are the contents of private github repositories encrypted at rest? (e.g. similarly to how [google drive and drop box are](https://www.virtru.com/blog/dropbox-encryption/))

I could not find a definitive answer online, but assume that files in private github repositories are not encrypted simply because it is not technically possible for github to perform its job (e.g. comparisons of current code with previous versions) if it cannot 'see' the code/data. My understanding is not good enough to say for sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article is quite a bit misleading (because it attempts to sell you some service). Both google and dropbox actually own the encryption keys for your data and can easily see it. From a security perspective they are only protecting data from a hacker (or technician) that got access to their data storage facilities, but not to the server infrastructure.

I don't know whether github encrypts the data at-rest, but it increases the security only marginally. If you don't want something to be read – you should own your encryption keys and preform encryption operations on your machine, not to trust some service to keep your data safe.